# How To Create and Run WebView in a new Thread?

Tags: android, webview

How to Run WebView in a new Thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
class demo implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try{  
           WebView mywebview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
           mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
       }catch (Exception e){

           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    demo obj = new demo();
    Thread t = new Thread(obj);
    t.start();
}

}
```

Its showing giving me exception.

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from
>   field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null
>   object reference
>           at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:229)
>           at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:137)
>           at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.ensureChromiumStartedLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:9042)

Comment: `WebView` doesn't like to be instantiated on a non-UI thread, IIRC. A user had a similar issue with `WebView` and `AsyncLayoutInflater` a while ago. There's really no point in what you're attempting anyway. `WebView` itself is already going to be running everything it can on worker threads.

Comment: I wanna use the webview in backgroud. No needs to change view in main Thread. I am creating an app that will load a webview in background. For example my app will load youtube.com in webview and click some buttom using javascript( play some song), and everything will be on background. and I will trigger this event on a specific time everyday.

Comment: Well, you can't instantiate it or perform any `View` operations on it from a non-UI thread, so you're going to have to do at least those things from the main thread. I'm not too familiar with running JavaScript in a `WebView`, but I'm pretty sure it's already running that on a separate thread anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wanna do that? Creating `WebView` and loading url **is fine** when you do it on the mainThread. If you want update view you must do it on mainThread.

If you are using a simple Thread then using `Handler` or message or `runOnUiThread` you can update the view of main thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private Handler uiHandler;
  private WebView webView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uiHandler = new Handler();
    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
  }

  // This method is to be executed on the new thread.
  public void simulate() {
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // This is run on the UI thread.
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I wanna use the webview in backgroud. No needs to change view in main Thread.
I am creating an app that will load a webview in background. For example my app will load youtube.com in webview and click some buttom using javascript( play some song), and everything will be on background. and I will trigger this event on a specific time everyday.